# Compress components with gzip doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I use this in my .htaccess to make compression but still some online services like GTmetrics say I don't have compression.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
#The following line is enough for .js and .css
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript

#The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>
```

I know there is a lot of questions like this and I tried many things include Google but whenever I put in .htaccess result is the same - No gzip compression.

Comment: what version of Apache are you using? Also if you have external js you wont be able to compress those and it flag that. e.g. Google plus button js etc.

Comment: Apache version `2.2.26` and yes, I have Google+ button and some external js.